# Websocket Binary message from Tomcat 9 to client splitted to 2 or more tcp packets

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, websocket

I am using Tomcat 9 and Spring.

My web application has a websocket service.

My application sends binary messages to client using `sendMessage` of:

```
org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession.
```

I collected tcp packets by [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org). I see that every binary websocket message uses at least 2 TCP packets.

The first packet is the header, it is small.

It seems that Java code always send header and then rest data.

How to fix this behavior?
Is it Spring or Tomcat issue?

Comment: I founded - this is Tomcat issue.

Answer (score -1):

The underlying problem was a bug in the tomcat implementation. Their send method for websocket messages took a list of message blocks to send and iterated through them calling send() and flush() for each buffer. As they encode the header in a separate buffer the header and body would thus be written to the wire in different datagrams as you rightly identified. I looked into the issue and found you had tried to submit a patch to them which they rejected due to additional memory allocations.

I proposed another fix to them where they simply call flush() once after all blocks have been written, rather than in between each block. This causes all parts of the message to go in a single datagram when possible without adding any additional memory allocations. I tested the fix in my project and verified it, and tomcat has adopted it for their next release.

The fix will be included in 8.5.X and 9.0. You must upgrade tomcat to resolve this behavior.

I'm providing a link to the issue in tomcat's github for reference.

https://github.com/apache/tomcat85/commit/47c211eb3ee7f9be2df6c313fb65351feabd42d1